# Order doctrine to-many associations by foreign attribute

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-many

Is it possible to order a to-many association using a foreign attribute?

For example: Say there are 3 entities Client , Order and Dish. For the sake of argument, say that there is a one-to-many association between Client and Order, and there is a many-to-one association between Order and Dish. And that Dish has a field named price

So, a client can put many orders, and each order corresponds to one dish.

I would want to sort the one-to-many association by the price of the dish. i.e. , to have a getOrders() method for the Client entity that returns the Orders sorted by $order->getDish()->getPrice().

I know that I could implement this function by using a Query (i don't want this, because i don't have access to the repository in the Client Entity), or by sorting the orders in memory (which is slower), but i would rather let Doctrine do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use annotations

```
**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dish")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"price" = "DESC"})
 */
private $dish;
```

My answer is based upon your description but I'm not sure that one order could have only one dish (otherwise ordering would be useless, I'm I wrong?)

If you need to change relationship cardinality, of course, you can: the earth of the answer is `OrderBy` annotation

Comment: No, i don't want to order the dishes, i want to order the Orders (might not be a good example)

Comment: @WardBeullens ok, I didn't understood the question. I'm not sure you can do it without passing from repos or writing you own DQL query

Comment: Ideally i would want an annotation @ORM\OrderBy({"dish.price" = "DESC"}) or something similar.